# Unity game screen stuttering on iPad

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ipad

I developed a simple mobile game for iOS using Unity engine. I set `vSyncCount` to 0 and `targetFrameRate` to 40 for iPhone and to 60 for iPad. Game is running absolutely smooth on iPhone XS/XS Max/7+/SE but I see the strange screen stuttering (I can see difference between frames) on iPad Pro. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: When I had this issue I was moving the camera in the wrong function: I had mixed up the Update and the FixedUpdate

Comment: Yes, I am updating all logic in Update and updating my camera in LateUpdate